# HTTP Post from Console application C#

Tags: c#, console, httpwebrequest

I have web site that contains textbox and button, when enter something in the textbox and click the button the site redirect to another one.

My question is how to get the redirected URL using console application , and how to pass the textbox value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/debx8sh9.aspx) describe how to post data using HttpWebRequest. Set property [HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) false and process [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) and [GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You probably would need a proxy to trap the response and then you can redirect from that proxy. Try using burpsuite it is a proxy which will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to define service
that will receive a value and will
return URL . The service will be called from 
the web site or console application.
You can use wcf , old asmx

The value can be passed as parameter to your web method .

Comment: Can you explain more so I can help you

Comment: there is site giving  it article number and it redirect you to the article website ,and this site doesn't have web service